# Is there a difference between "summon" and "resummon"?

Tags: hearthstone

I was just confused when playing against the Curator. He played [image: Moat Lurker]

which he used to destroy one of my minions. After Moat Lurker died my minion was resummoned on my side of the board. I expected it to be resummoned on his side.

There are cards which lets you summon minions for your opponent (e.g. Leeroy, The Beast, Hungry Dragon, etc.). But if the card text reads "summon" without "for your opponent" it was always meant that you summon it on your side as far as I know.

So, obviously Moat Lurker summons the minion on that side where he destroyed it. In my opinion this is quite inconsistent to the behavior of

[image: Mirror Entity]

which summons the minion on the players side of the board who played the secret. I am sure I could find some more examples of seeming inconsistencies, if I searched for them.

The only difference which could explain the different behavior to me are the words "summon" and "resummon".

The question: What is the rule here?

Comment: For me resummon means summon again after a death, for this card. But when you take Resurrect, it's summon, not resummon. So maybe the minion keeps his atk/hp after the resummon...

Comment: At the end of the day, behaviour in hearthstone is determined by the code, not the wording, and the wording can be inconsistent.  Sometimes the only way to know what will happen in a given situation is to try it out, or look online to see what happened when other people try it out.

Answer (score 4):

Imo, in this case the "it" part of the description is important.

Usually the descriptions are like "summon a copy of the minion", or "summon a minion for the oponent".

In this case it sais "resummon IT". The one that died. That minion was on your opponent side and since is the same minion it remained there (is not a copy, it is the exact same minion). So the description looks accurate to me.

What I would like to test is what happens if the specific minion was buffed. Will it be resummoned with the buffs (I'm guessing not, but since it is the same... maybe)?

Comment: Just happened in a game: No, the minion is resummoned without buffs.

Answer (score 0):

(re)summon "it"

vs

summon a COPY of "it"

The key is the copy for mirror entity. Else the minion sticks to it's owner. Moat lurker on death will resummon the minion back to whoever owned it. So you can do it to your side as well (as a kind of heal, trade avoidance).

So to reiterate, the minion is very much tied to its owner.

Comment: That's your interpretation. Another one would be that the owner is a property of a minion, like the minion destroyed by the Lurker still has it. Why is this property not copied when summoning the "copy"?

Comment: ? I think that's consistent with the english word "copy". A "copy" i might make of something you "own" is owned by me - ownership lies with the maker. I think you're confusing it with data structures in CS, specifically a deepclone. Mirror image - your spell makes you a "copy" of the enemy minion played. Moat lurker destroys and resummons the "same" minion. So yes if you blindly used a deepclone to make a copy and the object had an "owner" field / property - it would likely be a bug.